# Set focus to an mdi container after showing an mdi child

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I'm trying to make a form that is an MDI container, and when I press a button on the numpad (1-9), a small form (that will be the form's MDI child) will appear in the relative location to the position of the digit in the numpad (5 is in the middle, 9 is top right), and then I want the focus of the program to return to the mdi container so you can press the button again.

I have a keypress event in my MDI container set up like this:

```
private void MdiClient_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            int num;
            if (e.KeyChar >= '1' && e.KeyChar <= '9')
            {
                num = e.KeyChar - '0';
                PhysicalChild pc = new PhysicalChild();
                pc.MdiParent = this;
                pc.Show();
                pc.Location = new Point(num % 3 * Width / 2 - 50 * num, num / 3 * Height / 2 - 50 * num);
                pc.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                Focus();
            }
        }
```

The problem is it doesn't return the focus to the MDI container, not even if I click the mouse on the container area, I have to close the MDI child for it to receive more button presses.

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: @AnnL. Forget about the second problem, turned out my formula is wrong, but what about the first problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, when there are MDI child forms, they will always have the focus.  The MDI parent only gets the focus when there are no child forms that can hold the focus.

But, from what I've read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#child) about child windows, you can change the parent window property on the child to Null.  That will decouple the child from the parent ... which ought to have the effect of making your MDI window childless again.  (Disclaimer:  I haven't actually tried this, so I don't know if it will solve your problem.)

If that doesn't work, an MDI window may not be the best solution for your application.  MDI windows are usually empty containers, except for a menu:  they don't tend to have content of their own.

Comment: Oh... But I can still make events for the children that will affect the parent.

Comment: Yes: the parent just has to subscribe to the child's event (handle it with an event handler.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect and the focus return to mdiParent. 
The problem is in your child load try to empty it and then try your code again it work like a charm.
I did test it.

Your Code must be like this:

```
 public partial class  PhysicalChild : Form
    {
        public  PhysicalChild()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PhysicalChild_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this.MdiParent.Text );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I add a PhysicalChild like this: `public PhysicalChild(Form1 parentForm) { MdiParent = parentForm;      Show(); }`. What's wrong here?

Comment: Try to comment your rows in the constructor because you don't need them to show a form, but when you call the method pc.Show(); it call Form (pc) LoadEvent and there you can put other code. The Form1 parentForm is redoundand becouse you have parent form in the (this.ParentForm property of PhysicalChild Form class).

Comment: It says it cannot resolve "InitializeComponent()", I copied the code exactly.

Comment: Sorry, you need a new Windows Form in you Project and call it PhysicalChild and then double click on it to generate LoadEvent. the new form is your child form. The InitializeComponent() is generated automatically from Visual Studio and it used to set default property values of yours components on the form.

Comment: It doesn't work, only if I combine your method with Ann's answer to register events in the child windows.

Comment: I tested it before to answer to you and it work perfectly "Your Code" I just add new empty form. What Ann say is in contrast to the results eccept for :" an MDI window may not be the best solution for your application. MDI windows are usually empty containers, except for a menu: they don't tend to have content of their own."

Comment: The Title of this post is: Set focus to an mdi container after showing an mdi child and the above code do it. If your intent was different please edit It.